# Hide angular files on the browser

Tags: angularjs, browser

My question may be inapropriate but I'm asking anyway. When I check some websites developped with angular, with the code inspector you don't see the applications JS files (app.js, controller, ...). But when I'm checking mine I see everything and it can bring a large security issue.

Do you know the way of "hiding" them please ? Thanks in advance.
[Picture showing what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSGJs.jpg)

Comment: You want to bundle all you files into single one.

Comment: @dfsq how do we do that ? And what is the point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bundle your files in one single file. During this process you can even minify and/or uglify your code so that it is more hard to read. This should be done for production only because in development, you want to be able to debug your code with readable code.

You can use tools like gulp which is pretty easy to master and can do a lot of great automated stuff for prod and dev environment.

Here is a nice [Getting Started with Gulp](https://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/) or go to the [Official Website](http://gulpjs.com/)

If you make a search in SO with ["gulp bundle"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gulp%20bundle), im sure you will find some similar questions.

Comment: Yes I've recently seen that Gulp and similar tools can do the work. I'll check on it. Thanks you.